# How to add to cart different store's product in one cart only magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2, checkout, multistore, shipping-methods

I've created 5 stores in Magento 2, I want to add products of those stores in one cart only and different shipping method of the different store on one checkout page.

Now my questions:

1. What should be the proper configuration of stores to achieve this?
2. Is it possible to achieve this in Magento 2?

[image]

[image]

Comment: found any solution?

Comment: no, not at the moment